# Converting Autofac to Simple Injector

Tags: c#, autofac, simple-injector

In Autofac I can do the following

```
builder
.RegisterType<Services.GreetService>()
    .As<ServiceBase>()
.InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Where GreetService inherits from ServiceBase

I would like to do the same sort of thing with Simple Injector.

Does anybody know how?

Thanks

**Update 1**

I found this article where they use autofac in a windows service: http://www.turbulentintellect.com/2011/02/anatomy-of-windows-service-part-2.html

I have been trying to replace Autofac with Simple Injector but I can't get the resulting service to install. The error I receive is System.ArgumentException: Must specify value for source. This usually points to the ServiceName not matching in the ServiceInstaller and the Service.

Everything is set up as per the article except the below:

```
internal class ServiceBootstrapper
{
    //public IContainer Build()
    //{
    //    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    //    builder
    //        .RegisterType<GreetService>()
    //        .As<ServiceBase>()
    //        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    //    builder
    //        .RegisterType<ServiceNameProvider>()
    //        .As<IServiceNameProvider>()
    //        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    //    builder
    //        .RegisterType<Greeter>()
    //        .As<IGreeter>()
    //        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    //    return builder.Build();
    //}

    public Container Build()
    {
        var container = new Container();
        
        container.RegisterLifetimeScope<ServiceBase, GreetService>();
        container.RegisterLifetimeScope<IServiceNameProvider, ServiceNameProvider>();
        container.RegisterLifetimeScope<IGreeter, Greeter>();

        container.Verify();

        return container;
    }
}

internal class InstallBootstrapper
{
    //public IContainer Build()
    //{
    //    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    //    builder
    //        .RegisterType<HelloServiceProcessInstaller>()
    //        .As<Installer>()
    //        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    //    builder
    //        .RegisterType<GreetServiceInstaller>()
    //        .As<Installer>()
    //        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    //    builder
    //        .RegisterType<Config.ServiceNameProvider>()
    //        .As<Config.IServiceNameProvider>()
    //        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    //    return builder.Build();
    //}

    public Container Build()
    {
        var container = new Container();

        container.RegisterLifetimeScope<HelloServiceProcessInstaller>();
        container.RegisterLifetimeScope<GreetServiceInstaller>();
        container.RegisterLifetimeScope<IServiceNameProvider, ServiceNameProvider>();

        container.Verify();

        return container;
    }
}

public static class Program
{
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            var iocBootstrap = new ServiceBootstrapper();
            var container = iocBootstrap.Build();

            var services = container.GetInstance<ServiceBase>();

            ServiceBase.Run(services);

            //var services = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<ServiceBase>>();

            //ServiceBase.Run(services.ToArray());
        }
}

[RunInstaller(true)]
public class ProjectInstaller : Installer
{
    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        var bootstrapper = new InstallBootstrapper();
        var container = bootstrapper.Build();

       var processInstallers = container.GetInstance<ServiceProcessInstaller>();
       var serviceInstaller = container.GetInstance<ServiceInstaller>();

        //var installers = container.GetInstance<IEnumerable<Installer>>();
    //var installers = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<Installer>>();

   //Installers.AddRange(installers.ToArray());
       Installers.Add(processInstallers);
       Installers.Add(serviceInstaller); 
    }
}
```

I am definitely missing something here but can't seem to work out what.

**Update 2**

When I use InstallUtil to install the service I receive the below in the install log

> Running a transacted installation.
>
> Beginning the Install phase of the installation. See the contents of
> the log file for the C:\Local
> Development\HelloSvc\HelloSvc\bin\Debug\HelloSvc.exe assembly's
> progress. The file is located at C:\Local
> Development\HelloSvc\HelloSvc\bin\Debug\HelloSvc.InstallLog.
>
> An exception occurred during the Install phase.
> System.ArgumentException: Must specify value for source.
>
> The Rollback phase of the installation is beginning. See the contents
> of the log file for the C:\Local
> Development\HelloSvc\HelloSvc\bin\Debug\HelloSvc.exe assembly's
> progress. The file is located at C:\Local
> Development\HelloSvc\HelloSvc\bin\Debug\HelloSvc.InstallLog.
>
> The Rollback phase completed successfully.
>
> The transacted install has completed.

As previously mentioned this is usually do to the ServiceName being set incorrectly but I don't see how this is possible in this scenario.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything? What problems do you have with the conversion? Have you tried `container.Register<ServiceBase, GreetService>()`? Or if you want the [fancy lifetimescoping](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ObjectLifestyleManagement#PerLifetimeScope) `container.Register<ServiceBase, GreetService>(new LifetimeScopeLifestyle());`

Comment: About your update: you'll have to be more specific than "a want to achieve the same as in that article". I tried to read that article, but it's still unclear what your problems are. If you can't figure out why an exception is thrown, please include the exception details.

Comment: Also note that Simple Injector makes an explicit distinction between normal registrations and registration of collections. For registration/resolving collections you need to use `RegisterAll<T>`/`GetAllInstances<T>` or `RegisterAll<T>`/`GetInstance<IEnumerable<T>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't described what problems do you have with the conversion, so I try to answer two possible question/problem:

Registering classes for their base classes also supported by Simple Injector with the  `Register` method:

```cs
var container = new Container();
container.Register<ServiceBase, GreetService>();
```

And if you have problem with the `InstancePerLifetimeScope` part then you can find the similar `LifetimeScopeLifestyle` in the  [Lifetime Scoping Extensions](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ObjectLifestyleManagement#PerLifetimeScope) and you can use it with:

```cs
var container = new Container();
container.Register<ServiceBase, GreetService>(
    new LifetimeScopeLifestyle());
```

or optionally the using the `RegisterLifetimeScope` extension method from the same package:

```cs
var container = new Container();
container.RegisterLifetimeScope<ServiceBase, GreetService>();
```

Regarding you service installation problem:

In the `InstallBootstrapper` you need to register the `HelloServiceProcessInstaller` as `ServiceProcessInstaller` and the `GreetServiceInstaller` as `ServiceInstaller` because later you try to resolve them as `ServiceProcessInstaller` and `ServiceInstaller`:

```
internal class InstallBootstrapper
{
    public Container Build()
    {
        var container = new Container();

        container.RegisterLifetimeScope<ServiceProcessInstaller, 
                                        HelloServiceProcessInstaller>();
        container.RegisterLifetimeScope<ServiceInstaller, 
                                        GreetServiceInstaller>();
        container.RegisterLifetimeScope<IServiceNameProvider, 
                                        ServiceNameProvider>();

        container.Verify();

        return container;
    }
}
```

And in the `ProjectInstaller` because of the `RegisterLifetimeScope` you need to create a  LifetimeScope with the `BeginLifetimeScope:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class ProjectInstaller : Installer
{
    public ProjectInstaller()
    {

        var bootstrapper = new InstallBootstrapper();
        var container = bootstrapper.Build();

        using(container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var processInstallers = 
                  container.GetInstance<ServiceProcessInstaller>();
            var serviceInstaller = 
                  container.GetInstance<ServiceInstaller>();
            Installers.Add(processInstallers);
            Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
        }
    }
}
```

By the why you don't need the `LifetimeScope` at all in the installer, so you can write:

```
internal class InstallBootstrapper
{
    public Container Build()
    {
        var container = new Container();

        container.Register<ServiceProcessInstaller, 
                                        HelloServiceProcessInstaller>();
        container.Register<ServiceInstaller, 
                                        GreetServiceInstaller>();
        container.Register<IServiceNameProvider, 
                                        ServiceNameProvider>();

        container.Verify();

        return container;
    }
}

[RunInstaller(true)]
public class ProjectInstaller : Installer
{
    public ProjectInstaller()
    {

        var bootstrapper = new InstallBootstrapper();
        var container = bootstrapper.Build();

        var processInstallers = 
                  container.GetInstance<ServiceProcessInstaller>();
        var serviceInstaller = 
                  container.GetInstance<ServiceInstaller>();
        Installers.Add(processInstallers);
        Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);           
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks don't know how I missed that. I have updated my question. If you have a chance do you mind having a look

Comment: Excellent, that has sorted the problem. Did not know how to register two dependencies with Installer base class and resolve them. Steven hints to this with RegisterAll<T> but will have to have a play. Thanks a bunch.